# not working RegExp for pairs of repeating numbers (JS)

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I want to go through the content of a string via this RegExp, and simply ascending pairs of numbers by one.

example

from:

```
<b>text</b> "1"  <b>text</b> "1"
<b>text</b> "1"  <b>text</b> "1"
<b>text</b> "1"  <b>text</b> "1"
...
```

to:

```
<b>text</b> "1"  <b>text</b> "1"
<b>text</b> "2"  <b>text</b> "2"
<b>text</b> "3"  <b>text</b> "3"
until the nth number...
```

the snippet above represent only the parts who needs to be replaced,
where "text" and tags could be anything, since i have no control of the html input...

see how the current script looks:
http://jsfiddle.net/cVQEj/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your correctly, this should help:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mishik/cVQEj/3/)

```
return temp.replace(/"(\d)"(.*?)"\1"/g, function (all, i, whitespace) {
    n += 1;
    return '"' + n + '"' + whitespace + '"' + n + '"';
});
```

Temp string:

```
id="1" some text "1",  id="1" some text "1",  id="1" some text "1",
```

Output:

```
id="1" some text "1",  id="2" some text "2",  id="3" some text "3",
```